# Can a PHP variable be used as a table name in an SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a variable $table which will hold the value of the user input
I want to use the variable $table in my sql statement after the FROM.

Ex:

```
Select * FROM $table;
```

I want to know if its possible how I have written it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but a very bad practice and the way of doing it is different.

Comment: $dbquerystring = "Select * FROM ".$table;